# Extracting elements from two lists of dicts if other elements match using comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

How can I iterate over two lists of dicts, match dicts between the lists by a key, and if there is a match then append a specific key from each dict into a key value pair in a new dictionary. Let me clarify with an example:

```
l1 = [{'id': 52, 'email': 'someemail@yahoo.com', 'anotherfield': 'some value'},
       .....
      {'id': 98, 'email': 'anotheremail@yahoo.com', 'anotherfield': 'another value'}]

l2 = [{'id': 93, 'email': 'someemail@yahoo.com', 'another key': 'seventeen'},
       .....
      {'id': 101, 'email': 'anotheremail@yahoo.com', 'another key': 'twenty'}]


# match the 'email' keys between each list, and if match, create k, v pair from id's

desired_output = {'52': 93.....'98': 101}
```

I can achieve this quite easily by simply iterating over each list as follows:

```
lookup = dict()
for l in l1:
    for p in l2:
        if l['email']==p['email']:
            lookup[l['id']]=p['id']
            break
```

However this is a bit clunky and I'd prefer some kind of comprehension. My attempt:

```
lookup = {k['id']: v['id'] for k, v in zip(l1, l2) if k['email'] == v['email']}
```

Comment: Your for-loop is fine. But if you are going to use a comprehension, you'd need `{... for l in l1 for p in l2 if l['email']==p['email']}` note how it aligns with your for-loop. However, you won't be able to break, making this less ideal. In any event, there are better algorithms than a brute-force check, so, I'd rather change *that* than convert from a perfectly fine for-loop to comprehension.

Comment: Interesting, could you provide the full line with your suggested edit?

Comment: `{l['id']:p['id'] for l in l1 for p in l2 if l['email']==p['email']}`

Comment: This worked really nicely, thanks for the help, and I'll take a look into other methods that might be more robust. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, at the very least stick with your for-loop because at least you break out early.

Comment: The order of elements in lists is consistency? If not, algorithm is not working. `if k['email'] == v['email']` will works then `k[N] == v[N]`. You need consist of lists and when run your solution. Or, you can create one dict from your lists: `d = defaultdict(list)`, `d[email].append(id)`

Comment: @MaximPanfilov yes, grouping by e-mail and then iterating over the groups would be a linear time solution, at the cost of auxiliary space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from itertools import product
lookup = {k['id']: v['id'] for k, v in product(l1, l2) if k['email'] == v['email']}
```

Comment: This is definitely working so thanks for that. Is there any solution which wouldn't involve importing an additional module?

Comment: importing itertools does not have a lot of costs. but to answer to your question is should say yes. but you should implement product your self(to match all of items from both list together)

Answer (score 1):

Solution for unconsistency lists:

```
l1 = [{"email": "email1", "id": 1}, {"email": "email2", "id": 2}, {"email": "email3", "id": 3}]
l2 = [{"email": "email2", "id": 22}, {"email": "email4", "id": 4}, {"email": "email1", "id": 11}, ]

emails = {}
lookup = {}

for el in l1:
    emails[el["email"]] = el["id"]

for el in l2:
    email = el["email"]
    if email in emails:
        lookup[emails[email]] = el["id"]

# {1: 11, 2: 22}
print(lookup)

# bad solution from question
lookup = {k['id']: v['id'] for k, v in zip(l1, l2) if k['email'] == v['email']}

# {} - empty
print(lookup)
```

If you need more lists - extend solution, update emails dictionary on all loops before finally loop